# c# Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, authentication, httpclient, tls1.2, mutual-authentication

I'm trying to make a get request with mutual authentication 
There is some problem with HTTPS Handshake

I used fiddler to see what is send to server and see the response from it

Request:

```
CONNECT test.api.bgw.baltics.sebgroup.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: test.api.bgw.baltics.sebgroup.com

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 5E A8 0A E9 DB 60 E1 45 5E 08 3B 58 DC A2 EA D3 11 6F 22 1D 8D D5 51 F2 47 56 E5 54 B6 AB 9D 80
"Time": 23/11/2093 06:43:10
SessionID: empty
Extensions: 
    server_name test.api.bgw.baltics.sebgroup.com
    supported_groups    x25519 [0x1d], secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    signature_algs  rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_sha1, dsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
    SessionTicket   empty
    extended_master_secret  empty
    renegotiation_info  00
Ciphers: 
    [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C030]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02F]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [009F]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [009E]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C024]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C023]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C028]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C027]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C00A]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C014]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [009D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [009C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [003D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    [003C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

Response from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 13:52:25.353
Connection: close

fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to test.api.bgw.baltics.sebgroup.com (for #7) failed.
System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
< An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The code that i have is this:

```
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;


                HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                httpClientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
                httpClientHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
                httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (message, cert, chain, errors) => {
                    return true;
                };
                httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate("EEBGWTEST.crt"));
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
                //var result = httpClient.GetAsync("https://test.api.bgw.baltics.sebgroup.com/v1/accounts/EE211010220284954221/current-transactions").GetAwaiter().GetResult();


                var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://test.api.bgw.baltics.sebgroup.com/v1/accounts/EE211010220284954221/current-transactions");

                var result = httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null) MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
```

What could be the reason for this error?

One more interesting thing is that if i replay the request from fiddler it returns without an error

[image: fiddler log]

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 14:05:20.951
Connection: close
```

info about service authentication for this code
https://developer.baltics.sebgroup.com/bgw/docs/auth

Comment: Good information.  Use fiddler and compare first request headers from working and non working application.  Make the c# headers look like working application  What status do you get when failed instead of the 200 OK?.

Comment: I suspect that the latest Net library defaults to tls1.3 when creating new X509Certificate().